# How to hide/show Tab Layout dynamically in a Coordinator Layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-tabs

I have a Coordinator layout which contains app bar layout which again contains the toolbar and the tab layout. I want to hide/remove the Tabs layout when a certain menu item is selected from the navigation drawer and then show it again when user comes back to the home fragment.

Any ideas on how to do this?